Does free will exist according to Advaita Vedanta?
Recently, I've read about the philosophy of determinism. It says we have no free will. In physics, something is either deterministic or indeterministic (random or probabilistic). There's no room for "will" in this equation, which seems fatalistic. It implies that every choice we make is already predetermined. I don't believe in the soul, but even if it does exist, it doesn't translate to free will. Even if the soul is making the decision, it cannot make decisions out of nowhere. The soul's decisions must not be random. And if they are not random, they must be determined by something else. Hence, the same problem arises again — no room for free will.
Advaita Vedānta talks about non-duality, which kind of suggests that we don't have "individual will." Hence, no free will once again. Is there any verse or interpretation that specifically addresses free will? If free will doesn't exist, then Mokṣa is also a predetermined ultimate goal. Here's a follow-up question: Can God have free will? I'm afraid He doesn't either.

see Gita, 18.60-61. There is no free will, but that does not mean to take a fatalistic view of one's fate or responsibilities. 'God' has no free will - the concept of free will implies thinking and making choices - within time and causality. This only exists within Maya, Niguna Brahman is beyond Maya, beyond time and causality.

"There's no free will", --> "don't take fatalistic view" How does that follow? Can you explain? "God is beyond time and causality" just means that His actions/wants/desires are inderministic. Inderminism doesn't imply to "free will" or even "will". The problem is still the same.

*indeterministic  *indeterminism
